# Class densities w/ SVM (LibSVM)

Tags: classification, svm

I have a question regarding number of class samples for training and testing with an SVM.

For my situation, my training and testing samples both have the same number of class 1 and class 2 representatives. These are very unequal. Typically for training I have # class 1 = 300 and # class 2 = 3000. Similarly for testing I have # class 1 around 300 and # class 2 around 3000.

I've looked into taking a subset of class 2 samples for training in order to make the balance equal. Yet, I've found that my classifier best performs when leaving the training data untouched. I'm wondering if this makes sense to anyone else, simply because my testing sample classes are similar to my training. I should note, I'm using the signed distance from the hyperplane in order to create ROCs and that's how I'm judging classifier performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't throw away any data**. Do not undersample the majority class. It makes perfect sense that you get better performance when you don't throw away part of your data.

For SVM specifically, you can assign a higher misclassification penalty to instances of the minority class to account for the class skew (`-wX` flags in LIBSVM). If you use area under the ROC curve as your metric, the class skew won't even matter much, since ROC curves are insensitive to these things.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :D helps hearing someone say that this makes sense